# set <td> color in <h:column> from backing bean

Tags: css, jsf, facelets, managed-bean

is there any way i can set the color of the text in the table data in jsf? i want to have different colors for `#{_component.displayName}` depending on the return value of a backing bean method.

```
    <h:dataTable styleClass="mytable" value="#{cart.items}" var="_component"> 

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header"><h3>Item</h3></f:facet>
            #{_component.displayName}
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set the style class on the `<td>` element, you've to use `columnClasses` attribute of the `<h:dataTable>`:

```html
<h:dataTable columnClasses="col1,col2,col3">
```

It accepts a commaseparated string of CSS class names which are to be applied on the individual columns in sequence. You can even let it refer to a bean property which autopopulates the desired string:

```html
<h:dataTable columnClasses="#{bean.columnClasses}">
```

Each styleclass will however be applied on the *entire* column. If you'd like to style an individual cell independently, you'd better to wrap it in an `<h:outputText>`:

```html
<h:outputText value="#{_component.displayName}" styleClass="#{_component.styleClass}" />
```

or

```html
<h:outputText value="#{_component.displayName}" styleClass="#{bean.styleClass}" />
```

or

```html
<h:outputText value="#{_component.displayName}" styleClass="#{bean.styleClass(component)}" />
```

Or if the cell covers multiple components, wrap them inside a `<h:panelGroup>` instead and set the `styleClass` on it.